# PyML: graphing the decision surface

Tags: python, data-visualization, svm, pyml

PyML has a function for graphing decision surfaces.

First you need to tell PyML which data to use. Here I use a sparsevectordata with my feature vectors. This is the one I used to train my SVM.

```
demo2d.setData(training_vector)
```

Then you need to tell it which classifier you want to use. I give it a trained SVM.

```
demo2d.decisionSurface(best_svm, fileName = "dec.pdf")
```

However, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
**deleted by The Unfun Cat**
    demo2d.decisionSurface(best_svm, fileName = "dec.pdf")
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyML/demo/demo2d.py", line 140, in decisionSurface
    results = classifier.test(gridData)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyML/evaluators/assess.py", line 45, in test
    classifier.verifyData(data)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyML/classifiers/baseClassifiers.py", line 55, in verifyData
    if len(misc.intersect(self.featureID, data.featureID)) != len(self.featureID) :
AttributeError: 'SVM' object has no attribute 'featureID'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to dive right into the source, because I have never used PyML. Tried to find it online, but I couldn't track down the `verifyData` method in the [PyML 0.7.2](https://bitbucket.org/rryan/pyml/src/6bc8ff53031c/PyML?at=default) that was online, so I had to search through downloaded source.

A classifier's `featureID` is only set in the `baseClassifier` class's `train` method (lines 77-78):

```
if data.__class__.__name__ == 'VectorDataSet' :
        self.featureID = data.featureID[:]
```

In your code, `data.__class__.__name__` is evaluating to `"SparseDataSet"` (or what ever other class you are using) and the expression evaluates to `False` (never setting featureID).

Then in `demo2d.decisionSurface`:

```
gridData = VectorDataSet(gridX)
gridData.attachKernel(data.kernel)
results = classifier.test(gridData)
```

Which tries to test your classifier using a `VectorDataSet`. In this instance `classifier.test` is equivalent to a call to the `assess.test` method which tries to verify if the data has the same features the training data had by using `baseClassifier.verifyData`:

```
def verifyData(self, data) :
  if data.__class__.__name__ != 'VectorDataSet' :
      return
  if len(misc.intersect(self.featureID, data.featureID)) != len(self.featureID) :
       raise ValueError, 'missing features in test data'
```

Which then tests the class of the passed data, which is now `"VectorDataSet"`, and proceeds to try to access the `featureID` attribute that was never created.

Basically, it's either a **bug**, or a hidden feature.

Long story short, You have to convert your data to a `VectorDataSet` because `SVM.featureID` is not set otherwise.

Also, you don't need to pass it a trained data set, the function trains the classifier for you.

**Edit:**

I would also like to bring attention to the `setData` method:

```
def setData(data_) :
    global data
    data = data_
```

There is no type-checking *at all*. So someone could potentially set `data` to *anything*, e.g. an integer, a string, etc., which will cause an error in `decisionSurface`.

If you are going to use `setData`, you must use it carefully (only with a `VectorDataSet`), because the code is not as flexible as you would like.

Comment: Thanks for doing excellent code detective work for such a measly sum.

Comment: Will try to add some examples and whatnot when I get time to look at your answer.